# Xcode version creating AudioKit import problems

Tags: audiokit

After a recent Xcode version install (10.2) my AudioKit import statements don't work

"Module compiled with Swift 4.2.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler: ".
I have thus far always used cocoa pods to install AudioKit.
Is the best thing to do here to revert Xcode and wait a while for the 5.0 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just pushed a pre-release pod (version 4.6.4.b1) compiled with Swift 5 on Xcode 10.2. You can use it by following the instructions on this page:

https://github.com/AudioKit/Specs

You can use that one until the next mainstream release compiled with Xcode 10.2 is pushed out, hopefully in the coming days.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reverting Xcode, downloading and installing the 10.1 toolchain from https://swift.org/builds/swift-4.2.3-release/xcode/swift-4.2.3-RELEASE/swift-4.2.3-RELEASE-osx.pkg

then setting Xcode | Toolchains to use the Swift 4.2.3 Release allows me to keep running the existing code until Swift 5 build issues are resolved.

Alternatively use the recently pushed working staging pod. Its version number is 4.6.4.b1 - instructions are here: https://github.com/AudioKit/Specs